# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on double array

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, arrays, memory-management

writing an objective c (with c low level functionality) function to detect pitch.  Getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 on the line "w[i] = i;" in the first for loop. In our iteration, numberofSamples = 32768.  The Error occurs in the first loop after i = 16332. For some reason after filling about half of the array, the pointer is no longer valid.  Single threaded app, nothing else should be messing around with stuff while this is running.  I was wondering if there were any fundamental errors in this setup that could cause this pointer error. I can provide more detail as requested.  Thanks!

```
NSArray* getMainFrequency(NSMutableArray *input,int numberOfSamples){
    const int log2n = log(numberOfSamples)/log(2);
    const int n = 1 << log2n;
    const int nOver2 = n / 2;
    int sFreq=44100;
    double fFreq=0,maxMag=0,realFreq=0,t,alpha=0.6;
    double mag[n/2+1],dblInput[numberOfSamples],w[numberOfSamples];

    FFTSetupD fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetupD (log2n, kFFTRadix2);

    for(int i=0;i<numberOfSamples;i++){
        dblInput[i]=[input[i] doubleValue];
        w[i] = i;
    }

    DSPDoubleSplitComplex fft_data;

    fft_data.realp = malloc(nOver2 * sizeof(double));
    fft_data.imagp = malloc(nOver2 * sizeof(double));

    vDSP_ctozD((DSPDoubleComplex *)dblInput, 2, &fft_data, 1, nOver2);


    vDSP_fft_zripD (fftSetup, &fft_data, 1, log2n, kFFTDirection_Forward);


    for (int i = 0; i < nOver2; ++i){
        fft_data.realp[i] *= 0.5;
        fft_data.imagp[i] *= 0.5;
    }

    for (int i = 48; i < 2974; ++i){
        mag[i]=pow((pow(fft_data.realp[i],2)+pow(fft_data.imagp[i],2)),0.5);
    }

    for(int i=48;i <= 2974;i++){  //to get a max of 4000 hZ hopefully?
       if (mag[i]>maxMag){
            maxMag = mag[i];
            fFreq = i;
        }
    }
    realFreq=fFreq/(numberOfSamples/2+1)*sFreq/2;
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @(maxMag),@(realFreq),nil];

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the value of `log2n` correct?

Comment: Why do you use the magic numbers `48` and `2974` instead of something calculated from `numberOfSamples`?

Comment: the log2n is correct, and the second response numbers correlate to ~65hz and ~4000hz, which is our frequencies of interest. Could have been written as numberOfSamples/sampleFrequency*4000 for 4000 hz as the maximum where sampleFrequency is 44100, or numberOfSamples/sampleFrequency*65 for 65 hz as the minimum